# Godaddy phpmailer smpt configuration

Tags: php, phpmailer

We have a site on godaddy server. We have a contact form. When user filled form, first we should send mail to our info@oursite, after we should send mail to user's mail from our info@oursite. My tried code below:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->port = 25;
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Username = 'username@example.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->addAddress($email, $name);
$mail->subject = 'Subject';
$mail->MsgHTML('mail içeriği');


if ($mail->Send()){
```

this outputs below:

[image]

it seems mail delivered, but it never delivered the message.
I tried many things;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

port 25,80,3535,465(with ssl),
tls, ssl authentication,

what should I do? what should I try more, any ideas?

Comment: Did you censor out stuff in that screenshot, or is part of the issue that you're not actually putting in any `To:` address? By the way, you should change your SMTP password at your host, since you put it in your post.

Comment: thanks I changed my pass, also I deleted some data like 'to: ...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're using a very old version of PHPMailer; [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

I don't know where you got your code, but you've got the case of some vital properties wrong - I suggest you base your code on the examples provided with PHPMailer. In particular, `subject` should be `Subject` and `port` should be `Port`. When sending to localhost you don't need a username or password, so you don't need to set them. Similarly, `Port` defaults to 25, so you don't need to set it.

You're not specifying a From address, and it looks like whatever address you're passing to `addAddress` is invalid, so you're sending a message from nobody to nobody - and not surprisingly it's not going anywhere!

It looks like your message body is in Turkish (?), which will not work in the default ISO-8859-1 character set, so I suggest you switch to UTF-8 by setting `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';`.

Check your return values when calling addAddress to make sure the submitted value is valid before trying to send to it.

With these things fixed:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$mail = new PHPMailer;
if (!$mail->addAddress($email, $name)) {
  die('Invalid email address');
}
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->msgHTML('mail içeriği');
$mail->setFrom('me@example.com', 'My Name');    

if ($mail->send()) {
    echo 'Sent';
} else {
    echo 'Error: '.$mail->Errorinfo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now it sends mail, but there is a little problem. When mail goes to hotmail, it dropped to spam folder and there is a warning like 'gmail/hotmail can not confirmed that this mail is from actually example.com or not' . I used Turkish language, when I do UTF-8 some char are accurate but some of is not accurate. What could be go wrong about that?

Comment: That it goes into spam is a separate problem that has many answers on here. There are a lot of things that can go wrong with UTF-8 data - search for it.

Comment: After a few research, I find the solution of my UTF-8 problem. In class.phpmailer.php class, I changed the line "public $CharSet = 'iso-8859-1' "  to  "public $CharSet = 'iso-8859-9' " .When you do this u don't need to set "$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8' " anymore.

Comment: Don't edit the library code. Just use `$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-9'` in your own code.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I changed it like u said.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I want to send an email to my email address which hosted on godaddy server. I used your answer as an example with changing some necessary line. It gives message 'message is sent', but I never get an email. If I change the target mail address, it works well. I couldn't understand. I tried hotmail, gmail, mynet, yandex mail address it works, but just my godaddy hosted mail address does not get email from localhost.

Comment: The script only submits to your local mail server - after that the script has no control over what happens to the message, but the mail server does, and you should find everything relating to onward delivery in your local mail server's log - usually `/var/log/mail.log`.