# PHP mail using Gsuit

Tags: php, phpmailer, smtp-auth

I am using PHP mailer to send email, Server is Godaddy. I am using SMTP Gmail Server. My email setup is on Gsuit, I am getting this error: **SMTP failed to Connect()**

```
<?php

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

    $email = "info@mydomain.com";                    
    $password = "CXTYDF";

    $to_id = $_POST['toid'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = $email;
    $mail->Password = $password;
    $mail->setFrom('info@mydomain.com', 'TeamSupport');
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@mydomain.com', 'TeamSupport');
    $mail->addAddress($to_id);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->msgHTML($message);

    if (!$mail->send()) {
    $error = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    ?>
        <script>alert('<?php echo $error ?>');</script>
    <?php
    } 
    else {
        echo '<script>alert("Message sent!");</script>';
    }

}
?>
```

After done some research on forums I found that instead of using

> $mail->isSMTP();

if I use  **$mail->SMTPAuth=true;** I am able to send mail successfully.

Now my question is: Is it safe to use this code. And after using this code I tried to use incorrect Password and email, and Surprisingly I am able to send email with fake credentials. How is it possible?

Comment: use godaddy smtp host

Comment: Read the error message, read the PHPMailer docs. This has been answered many times.

Comment: @rupesh Can you explain it little more, My Email server is Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Godaddy phpmailer smpt configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159539/godaddy-phpmailer-smpt-configuration)

Comment: use godaddy smtp host call to godaddy they will provide u thier smtp host

Comment: I have used godaddy smtp host, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Godaddy is not able to solve my prob, Can someone help.