# Webapplication hosted on CPanel and want to send SMTP email through webapp

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer, cpanel

I purchased GoDaddy Linux CPanel Shared Hosting. Then I have installed a web application on CPanel.

This application has a feature to communicate with a new user via email. For example, when a new user is registered, a confirmation email is sent. 
The email is sent from info@domainname.com

I am already having an email server on outlook.office365.com where I manage info@domainname.com email account. (I mean I can send, receive email here)

**Now the question is**

My web application has email settings where I have to provide SMTP email settings. I need to provide values like

- Port number:
- Security: SSL/ TLS
- Hostname:
- Username:
- Password:

So which details I have to enter here? 
It doesn't work when I entered my outlook.office365.com email

My purpose is just to send emails through this application.

**Please note:**
The web application also has an alternative to use phpmail() function, but all the emails sent using phpmail() are received in spam folder. That is why I want to use SMTP method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Godaddy phpmailer smpt configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159539/godaddy-phpmailer-smpt-configuration)

Comment: Read the PHPMailer docs on sending with GoDaddy and the many similar questions on here.

Comment: Hi @Synchro I went through the above reply and some possible discussion threads on GoDaddy as well. The thing is, I am not a programmer nor I have a PHP code with me to test email. This is a ready web-application. That is why I am confused which values should I provide in above configuration? The GoDaddy Forum says it is not possible in shared hosting and I have to purchase a dedicated server and email product from them. But I guess it is not a legit reply and I am sure there is a way. Could you help me?

Comment: Hi @Synchro I tried certain permutation and combination and finally was able to do it. The catch was I have to use the username and password of cPanel instead of the email.